# ActionBarActivity and FragmentActivity... "Inconvertible types"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm currently having a curious problem, trying to use simultaneously v4 and v7 (actionbar) compatibility libs.

Let's say I've got my own Activity class, that extends ActionBarActivity on one hand and, on the other hand a Fragment, inside of which I call "(MyActivity)getActivity()".

I checked the imports and my Fragment is a v4 Fragment.

In a v4 Fragment, calling "getActivity()" returns a FragmentActivity.

I also checked: ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity.

Now here is my problem:
I don't have any error in the editor (no red line).
I'm using Android Studio.
When I try to "Make" the project, the compiler returns an error for each time I call "getActivity" inside my Fragment.
It tells me he has a FragmentActivity but a ActionBarActivity is expected and tells me those classes are incompatible.
It interrupts and I can't even test my app.

It may be a problem with the gradle configuration, but I added "compile "compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+""  in the "dependencies" part of my build.gradle file, as said on this page:"http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html", and it doesn't change anything...

Any idea?

**EDIT :**
As an adddition to my yesterday's post, even if everything is explain before, here are some code parts and the error message Android-Studio gives me:

First of all, my activity:

```
...
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
...
public abstract class MyAbstractActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    //Do some stuff here
}
```

Every activity of my application extends this class.

Now here is my fragment:

```
...
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
...
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Do some stuff...
        ((MyAbstractActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    //Do some stuff...
}
```

No error is shown in the editor.
But when I "Make" the project, I get this message in the "Event Log":

> Compilation completed with 5 errors and 0 warnings in 4 sec

In the "Messages Make" part, I can see this for each time I try to cast "getActvity()" in "MyAbstractActivity":

> java: inconvertible types
>   required: com.myapps.abstracts.MyAbstractActivity
>   found: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: Did you add the cast to `ActionBarActivity`? Are you sure that your `Fragment` is an `androi.support.v4.app.Fragment` and not an `android.app.Fragment`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Concerning the activity, it extends ActionBarActivity, and in my fragment, I cast the result of "getActivity" to my Activity class. And yes, as I said, I checked my Fragment and it is really an androi.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit sabadow, I didn't know how to indent the code...  Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm sad to say that, but I finally downloaded Eclipse, imported my project, and solved my problem, using the error messages of Eclipse.
It told me to "Fix Project Properties", I clicked, it did everything on his side, I tryed to launch the app, it worked.
Now that the problem is fixed, when I come back to Android Studio, it works too... But, for the moment, I think I'm gonna stay with Eclipse... Too much time lost for nothing. :(

Comment: My fix was just to give up Android Studio at the moment... :-(

Comment: Aw that sucks. I'm also having a similar issue. Can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Android Eclipse plugin gets flaky. Try to clean your project, then rebuild. Also, try restarting Eclipse. Also verify your project build path library order. Also, try to rebuild from the command line in the project with 'ant clean; ant debug', but do it while Eclipse is closed.

Comment: I use Android Studio, this won't help me, unfortunately... But thank you for your answer.